why Relying Party doesn't honour IdentityServer's `IdentityTokenLifetime` setting?
I set IdentityTokenLifetime (https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/e9860c6488f90e8fbc11a4452b9dd111dbfae933/src/Storage/Models/Client.cs#L187) to a very small value 60 seconds, but after 60 seconds I (as user) refreshed page and I still remained signin, why is that? isn't that I should be prompted to enter username and password again? My understanding is, IdentityTokenLifetime results an "exp" with the matching value in the id token's payload, then this value is used to setup the user-to-relyingParty cookie's expire time. So after 60 seconds, the cookie should expire, then why I am still being able to remain signin?

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746403/why-is-the-identitytokenlifetime-default-to-300-sec "The identity token is a one-time only token", not a long-lived access token.

Under OAuth2/OIDC, a relying party is not required to use the ID token's exp claim for any purpose except decoding and verifying the ID token itself.
The RP does not have to derive their cookie expiration time from that claim, there is no expectation that they would do so, and this would be a weird/surprising thing for an RP to do.

thank you for your comment, I initially thought it is weird for an RP to use id token's exp claims just like you. But after checking the source code https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L1430 and https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs,295 , I found the RP still uses id token's exp in AuthenticationProperties which will be used to create user-to-RP cookie by CookieAuthenticationHandler

you need to set the authentication cookie lifetime to control how long a user can be signed in to your system. The exp in the token is only used for the initial validation of the ID-Token. The ID-token main use it to provide data for the authentication session cookie.

I still think the authentication cookie is based from the exp in the token, please refer to the source code https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L1430   you can see that AuthenticationProperties will contain the exp value and this AuthenticationProperties will be used to create a cookie by the cookie handler https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs,295

the expire inside the cookie is not the same as the expire of the cookie itself, the cookie expire you can see when the cookie is set in the response header or in the browsers cookie store.
